# getting photos from "Photos" app on Macbook to Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, raw

Is this possible? I was planning to just import my SD card and import that way, but somehow the files got deleted off my card. I am able to drag the pictures from "Photos" (Mac) onto my desktop and go via that route, but then they are jpegs instead of RAW files.

Comment: What is "photos" app?

Comment: On mac? It's just like the iPhone Photos app, but it's on my Macbook Air.

Comment: You say nowhere in the question it's on Mac...

Comment: Sorry! I posted quickly  and didn't realize?